# Scrollspy offset for a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed navbar, so I need a little offset when a certain element in the navbar is clicked, for which I used this code (It works perfectly fine for the navigation bar elements) :

```
    var offset = 68;

    $('.navbar li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
    scrollBy(0, -offset);
    });
```

But I have **two buttons** that also link to certain sections of the website:

```
<div id="main">
    <a href="denea.com"><img src="images/face.png" class="logo"></a>

    <div id="promo">
        <h2> So, your website doesn't look good anymore? <br><h3> We'll give it a second breath, then support you along the way.</h3></h2>
    </div>

    <div id="buttons">
        <a href="#portfolio"><button id="portbut">
         View portfolio
        </button></a>

        <a href="#contact"><button id="quotebut">
         Get a quote
        </button></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

But when I place their id's in the js  code I mention above, it's not working, the offset is not taken into consideration when "moving" to a certain section of the website.

What should I edit so the offset would be taken into consideration for those **two buttons** ?

Comment: have you tried giving those divs a class name as well and then using the class name in the js code? for example <div id="promo" class="promo">

Comment: @JakeTaylor thanks, but the issue was that <button> was wrapped in an <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

If someone ever needs it, the answer is:

```
var offset = 68;

    $('#buttons a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
    scrollBy(0, -offset);
    });
```